# How is the process of converting calcium carbonate (CaCO3) into calcium oxide (CaO)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, process-chemistry

I need to provide accurate information in relation to the production process of calcium oxide from calcium carbonate.

$$\ce{CaCO3 -> CaO + CO2}$$

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia article of calcium oxide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_oxide)

> Calcium oxide is usually made by the thermal decomposition of
>   materials, such as limestone or seashells, that contain calcium
>   carbonate ($\ce{CaCO3}$; mineral calcite) in a lime kiln. This is
>   accomplished by heating the material to above 825 °C (1,517 °F), a
>   process called calcination or lime-burning, to liberate a molecule
>   of carbon dioxide ($\ce{CO2}$), leaving quicklime.
>
> $$\ce{CaCO3(s) → CaO(s) + CO2(g)}$$
>
> The quicklime is not stable and, when cooled, will spontaneously react
>   with $\ce{CO2}$ from the air until, after enough time, it will be
>   completely converted back to calcium carbonate unless slaked with
>   water to set as lime plaster or lime mortar.